# How to create a dynamically changing table in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, view, scroll

Here is an example table image:

[image]

(For explanation purposes, lines are not overlapped in the image.)

The red area is a fixed part and represents the title.

And the green area has a fixed size with 3 columns, but new columns can be added. Soon, the green area should be able to scroll left and right. You can check more than 4 column table cells by scrolling the green area to the left or right.

The blue area contains the green area, and new rows can be added. Soon, the blue area should be able to scroll up and down. And, adding a row to blue area means that 2 columns in the blue area and 3 or more columns in the green area are added as one row.
(The number of columns of each row in the green area is the same.)

**Question 1:**
Can I create such a table using the TextBox, Grid, ScrollBar basic UI controls provided by WPF?

**Question 2:**
How should I compose the internal structure of the table UI? The first way I thought was to compose each row as a UserControl. But I'm not sure.

Comment: looks like DataGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can
2. I don't know the best way to do it but here is an example of something you probably don't want to do but which works. I only made xaml 3 lines and 6 columns but you can create all of this with the code behind... Maybe it can still help you even if it's bad:

   ```
    <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Top" />
    <ScrollViewer Height="250" >
        <DockPanel Background="AliceBlue" LastChildFill="False">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100">
                    <Label Content="Column1" Width="100"/>
                    <Label Content="Column2" Width="100"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100">
                    <Label Content="Column1" Width="100"/>
                    <Label Content="Column2" Width="100"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100">
                    <Label Content="Column1" Width="100"/>
                    <Label Content="Column2" Width="100"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width="500" Background="Green" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100">
                        <Label Content="Column3" Width="200"/>
                        <Label Content="Column4" Width="200"/>
                        <Label Content="Column5" Width="200"/>
                        <Label Content="Column6" Width="200"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100">
                        <Label Content="Column3" Width="200"/>
                        <Label Content="Column4" Width="200"/>
                        <Label Content="Column5" Width="200"/>
                        <Label Content="Column6" Width="200"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100">
                        <Label Content="Column3" Width="200"/>
                        <Label Content="Column4" Width="200"/>
                        <Label Content="Column5" Width="200"/>
                        <Label Content="Column6" Width="200"/>
                    </StackPanel>



                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
   ```